# How do I create a trigger where only the owner of a case can edit the OwnerId field

Tags: trigger, case, ownership

How do I make a trigger so that the OwnerId field, which is a Lookup(User) field of the Case object, can only be edited by the Owner of the record

Comment: What would happen if the case was assigned to a Queue?

Comment: @dyson that is a fair question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done using a validation rule; no need for a trigger.

Something like:

```
ISCHANGED(OwnerId) && PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) != $User.Id
```

Comment: You're a life savior